# Old Drive in new PC starts failing

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

I just made a new PC build. I connected a storage drive from my old build. It is giving intermittent (once every 2 hours or so) Windows lockups, I hear it spin up, then everything unfreezes.

I decided to check out my drives in Windows Disk Manager and I see about 900GB unallocated on the old drive (3TB capacity). I can't remember if I forgot to format the second partition or my drive is failing and it's losing data.

I open up CrystalDiskInfo and see the old drive has `Reallocated Sector Count` caution with raw value `850`.

Also, it's a Seagate drive (ST3000NC000) but Seatools can't detect it. The drive is about 4 years old, 48941 hours power on.

Oddly still, the drive was functioning fine (no lockups, seatools detectable) in my old build, then literally 24 hours later in my new build it starts to lockup.

**How can I tell if that unallocated portion I see in Disk Manager is lost data  (as a result of reallocated sectors) or just a partition I forgot to format?**

Comment: "I decided to check out my drives in Windows Disk Manager and I see about 900GB unallocated on the old drive (3TB capacity)." - This is due to MBR not your HDD failing.  Windows limits MBR partitions to 2 TB.

Comment: Was this an old limit (win7)? I just partitioned a 4TB drive in win10 and it shows up as one ~4TB block with not unallocated partitions.

Comment: You see it as a single 4 TB partition due to the fact you use GPT.  The 2 TB limit has to do with MBR not WIndows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour that you describe is one of a disk that is going in sleep mode and takes a while to un-sleep. The settings to prevent the sleep mode of the drive are in Windows somewhere under control panel -> hardware and sound -> power options-> edit plan settings -> change advanced power settings. You may have to search a bit to find the exact mouse clicks. Set the sleep mode for the drive to never.

It still is a mechanical device, so if you move it, shake it etc. that may have some effect on it's functioning.If you suspect a hrddrive, **BACKUP** !!You may do this already, but it is worth  warning again. If the re-allocated sector count increases, you might want to change the drive.

Right-click on the partition(s) on the disk in the Windows explorer (and add the total if you have more than one partition). If the total is about 3TB-900GB, the 900G is just unassigned space.

Comment: I just bumped up the sleep timer today, but haven't had time to test it since I'm backing it up. Is there anyway to tell whether the unallocated space is lost data or I just forgot to format the partition?

Comment: reallocated sectors has nothing to do with unallocated disc space.

Comment: @Moab: and 850 sectors is not 900GB.

Comment: Windows doesn't put "lost data" into a separate partition. If you open Disk Mgmt, you should be able to right-click on the space and create a partition & format it. As for Sleep -- you're not helping the drive by having it sleep & wake all the time; that's terrible wear-and-tear.  Just turn Sleep off for the drive except when the whole system Sleeps or hibernates, assuming this is not a laptop where a powered-up disk may use the battery when the system is not plugged-in.